# PHP $_GET product page PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, get

Hello everybody i have a ecommerce website with 20 products on but i am looking to expand my product list to 100 different products.

now instead of having 100 seperate pages for 100 different products i would like to use the $_GET variable to display all products on the same page depending on the product id.

i just don't know where to go from here as in pulling the information from the database and displaying it.

---PRODUCT.PHP---

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php';
if(isset($_GET['pid']) && empty($_GET['pid']) === false) {
$productid = htmlentities($_GET['pid']);
echo intval($_GET['pid']);
}else{
    header('Location: home.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

here is also my directory structure if it helps.

p_id,
P_name,
p_description,
p_category,
p_price,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would update the SQL query if I were you - so for example:

```
if(isset($_GET['pid']) {
    $pid = $_GET['pid]'; 
    $SQL = "SELECT stuff FROM Products WHERE id = " . $pid;
} else { 
    $pid = ''; 
}
```

This would only get the records for that specific product id that the user have selected by adding the WHERE clause with the value of `$_GET['pid']`

Comment: To have a specific number of results. Use the LIMIT tag, would also highly recommend looking into parameterized queries to protect from malicious injections

Comment: *PDO* being the question title, I was expecting a prepared statement...